# Elixir: passing a function from a module to map function

Tags: elixir

I wrote a simple `map` function (for learning purposes; I know about Enum.map):

```
defmodule MyList do
    def add_1([]), do: []
    def add_1([head | tail]), do: [ head + 1 | add_1(tail)]

    def map([], _mapFn), do: []
    def map([head | tail], mapFn), do: [ mapFn.(head) | map(tail, mapFn) ]
end
```

And I can easily use it in iex:

```
MyList.map [1,2,3], &(&1 + 1)
```

And well, I'm using an anonymous function, so no surprises there.

How can I call it using the function from the module itself?

```
iex(1)> MyList.map [1,2,3,4], MyList.add_1
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function MyList.add_1/0 is undefined or private. Did you mean one of:

      * add_1/1

    MyList.add_1()
```

I mean, it's not anonymous after all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put an `&` in front of it, so it passes the function rather than trying to call it.

```
MyList.map [1,2,3,4], &MyList.add_1/1
```

Notice the `&` in front of the (qualified) function name and the arity declaration after it.